# Make [x] tag an ex-tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

There are 8 question in [x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x). One of them amazingly only has that tag. None of them relates to the X display server.

Should we burninate this tag?

Notice: I neither have the privilege nor know how to burninate tags, somebody else's gotta do it...

Comment: Definately, the tag is all but superflous to almost every question its included in.

Comment: Once we get [Billing integration \[on hold\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438506/billing-integration) deleted, it will be gone.

Comment: ... And it's gone!

Comment: Make [x] tag an ex-tag

Comment: [x out](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/x) [x]

Comment: Shouldn't this question be tagged with [x]?

Comment: meh. I would have thought "[x] does not mark the spot"

Comment: Jeez, some people just want to watch the world burninate

Comment: Should we burninate it? `[x] yes [ ] no`

Comment: Probably there because people were too lazy to select a proper tag...

Comment: All the StackOverflow pirates are going to be pretty annoyed with you. How are they are they going to find their treasure now `[x]` now longer marks the spot:-)

Comment: For [x] in (tags) remove [x]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of removing the tag from (4) questions that still had the tag on it.

The tag should be removed within 6-8 weeks. <sub>(When the cleanup script runs, tonight)</sub>

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the other 3 with other tags, and facilitating the deletion of the garbage question with only this tag.

Comment: So much liberty!

Comment: You will be sentenced to courts, sooner or later....

Comment: bunch of libertarians

Comment: quick, open up more questions with the tag `X`